# Why is 0dp considered a performance enhancement?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-lint

An **answer** at the end of this question has been filled out, combining remarks and solutions.

### Question

I searched around but haven't found anything that really explains why *Android Lint* as well as some *Eclipse* hints suggest replacing some `layout_height` and `layout_width` values with `0dp`.

For example, I have a `ListView` that was suggested to be changed

**Before**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

**After**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

Similarly, it suggested changes to a *ListView item*. These all look the same before and after the changes, but I'm interested in understanding why these are performance boosters.

Anyone have an explanation of why? If it helps, here is general layout with the `ListView`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo_splash">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_upcoming" />

    </LinearLayout>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Answer

I'm putting in an answer here because it's really a combination of answers and referenced links below. If I'm wrong on something, do let me know.

From [What is the trick with 0dip layout_height or layouth_width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220404/what-is-the-trick-with-0dip-layout-height-or-layouth-width)

There are 3 general layout attributes that work with *width* and *height*

1. `android:layout_height`
2. `android:layout_width`
3. `android:layout_weight`

When a `LinearLayout` is *vertical*, then the `layout_weight` will effect the *height* of the child `View`s (`ListView`). Setting the `layout_height` to `0dp` will cause this attribute to be ignored.

**Example**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When a `LinearLayout` is *horizontal*, then the `layout_weight` will effect the *width* of the child `View`s (`ListView`). Setting the `layout_width` to `0dp` will cause this attribute to be ignored.

**Example**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The reason to want to ignore the attribute is that if you didn't ignore it, it would be used to calculate the layout which uses more CPU time.

Additionally this prevents any confusion over what the layout should look like when using a combination of the three attributes. This is highlighted by *@android developer* in an answer below.

Also, *Android Lint* and *Eclipse* both say to use `0dip`. From that answer below, you can use `0dip`, `0dp`, `0px`, etc since a zero size is the same in any of the units.

**Avoid wrap_content on ListView**

From [Layout_width of a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270278/layout-width-of-a-listview/4270471#4270471)

If you've ever wondered why `getView(...)` is called so many times like I have, it turns out to be related to `wrap_content`.

Using `wrap_content` like I was using above will cause all child `View`s to be measured which will cause further CPU time. This measurement will cause your `getView(...)` to be called. I've now tested this and the number of times `getView(...)` is called is reduced dramatically.

When I was using `wrap_content` on two `ListView`s, `getView(...)` was called 3 times for each row on one `ListView` and 4 times for each row on the other.

Changing this to the recommended `0dp`, `getView(...)` was called only once for each row. This is quite an improvement, but has more to do with avoiding `wrap_content` on a `ListView` than it does the `0dp`.

However the suggestion of `0dp` does substantially improve performance because of this.

Comment: Similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220404/what-is-the-trick-with-0dip-layout-height-or-layouth-width

Comment: Nice find, I didn't find that one. The answer that wasn't accepted is the one that explains it

Comment: It threw me off to see the question have more votes than the top answer, but now I see why. Amazing Q&A. If you're willing, this would make for a great community wiki. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all you have this,

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

Never take the ListView's height as wrap_content, that will lead into troubles. [`Here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340718/726863) is the reason for that and [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270471/726863).

Further more,

> I searched around but haven't found anything that really explains why
>   Android Lint as well as some Eclipse hints suggests replacing some
>   layout_height and layout_width values with 0dp.

Its because you are using `layout_weight = "1"` that means your ListView with take the height as much as is available to it. So, in that case there is no need of using `layout_height = "wrap_content"` just change it to `android:layout_height="0dp"` and ListView's height will be managed by `layout_weight = "1"`.

Answer (score 13):

So when android:layout_weight is used on View X and LinearLayout is horizontal, then X's android:layout_width is simply ignored.

Similar, when android:layout_weight is used on View X and LinearLayout is vertical, then X's android:layout_height is ignored.

This actually means, that you can put anything in those ignored fields: 0dp or fill_parent or wrap_content. It doesn't matter. But it's recommended to use 0dp so View's do not do extra calculation of their height or width (which is then ignored). This small trick simply saves CPU cycles.

from :

[What is the trick with 0dip layout_height or layouth_width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220404/what-is-the-trick-with-0dip-layout-height-or-layouth-width#answer-7220491)

Answer (score 6):

as far as i know , there is a difference between using 0dp (or 0px btw, it's the same since 0 is 0 no matter what is the unit here ) and the wrap_content or fill_parent (or match_parent, it's the same).

it depends on the weight you use . if you only use weight of 1 , they all look the same , but the meaning is always different , and it is important for performance.

in order to show this , try the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px" android:text="1" android:background="#ffff0000"
    android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:textSize="20sp" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px" android:text="2" android:background="#ff00ff00"
    android:layout_weight="2" android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:textSize="20sp" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px" android:text="3" android:background="#ff0000ff"
    android:layout_weight="3" android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then try to replace the 0px with match_parent . you will see that the result is very different.

usually , for both better understanding and for better performance , you would want to use 0px.

Answer (score 3):

`LinearLayout` measures all the children according to the `layout_width`/`layout_height` values, then divides up the leftover space (which may be negative) according to the `layout_weight` values.

`0dp` is more efficient than `wrap_content` in this case because it's more efficient to just use zero for the original height and then split the parent's full height based on the weight than to measure the child first and then split the remainder based on the weight.

So the efficiency comes from not measuring the child. `0dp` should be exactly as efficient (and produce exactly the same result) as `match_parent`, or `42px`, or any other fixed number.

Answer (score 2):

Caution re using android:layout_height="0dp"

I have found that in a ListView 
(with the recommended View recycling using convertView, see e.g. http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/), 
setting android:layout_height="0dp" for the row TextView can lead to text truncation for multi-line text content.

Whenever a TextView object that was previously used to display a text that fitted in a single line is recycled to display a longer text that needs more than one line, that text is truncated to a single line.

The problem is cured by using android:layout_height="wrap_content"