# Two tableLayout inside a linearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I would place two table layout inside a `Linearlayout`. But with my code, I can see only one table. That's the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+text_view/tw_nome"
            android:text="@string/tw_nome" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+edit_text/et_nome"
            android:hint="@string/et_nome"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+text_view/tw_cognome"
            android:text="@string/tw_cognome" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+edit_text/et_cognome"
            android:hint="@string/et_cognome"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+text_view/tw_sesso"
            android:text="@string/tw_sesso" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+radio_group/rg"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+radio_button/button_m"
                android:text="@string/button_m" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+radio_button/button_f"
                android:text="@string/button_f" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+button/button_salva"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_salva" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+button/button_annulla"
            android:text="@string/button_annulla" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Side-by-side or vertical?

If you're looking for side-by-side, try `layout_weight`. Also note the change in `layout_width`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >
            <!-- rows -->
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >
            <!-- rows -->
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

*Update* From the comments it was asked why `layout_width` should be set to `0dp`.

Setting `0dp` is an optimization when you use `layout_weight`. Setting width to `0dp` tells the layout to ignore `layout_height` and use `layout_weight` instead which in this case gives an even width to each `TableLayout`.

I actually asked this same question and got some useful answers if it's helpful [Why is 0dp considered a performance enhancement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016781/why-is-0dp-considered-a-performance-enhancement)

Comment: *This is if your LinearLayout's orientation is horizontal. Switch the width/height directives if your orientation is vertical.

Comment: can i ask you why the "0dp" for width or height?

Comment: I know it sounds awkward, but setting `0dp` is an optimization when you use `layout_weight`. Setting width to `0dp` tells the layout to ignore `layout_height` and use `layout_weight` instead.

Comment: I asked the same question and posted as question on this and got some useful answers. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016781/why-is-0dp-considered-a-performance-enhancement

Answer (score 2):

Both table layouts widths and heights are defined as `match_parent`, so they are taking the same space as the parent. You don't have enough space in the parent for tow children to display both with the same size as the parent.

How you would solve this depends on the parent LinearLayout's orientation.

Answer (score 1):

put the LinearLayout inside a:

```
<ScrollView/>    </ScrollView>
```